# CMake add_custom_command is running on the first build when it should not

Tags: cmake

### Summary

I have a project which relies on source code generated by an external tool (MATLAB/Simulink) which other developers on the team may or may not have. The project therefore needs to handle both:

- The case where the generated code exists (e.g. checked in to source control along with the Simulink model) but the external tool does not
- The case where the external tool exists and it needs to call out to it to regenerate the code when the Simulink model changes

### CMake Approach

1. Determine if MATLAB/Simulink is available on the system.
2. Determine if the generated code already exists (look for the existence of a specific header in a specific location).

   - If the generated code already exists, don't waste time and just move on to step 3.
   - If the generated  code does not exist but MATLAB/Simulink *was* found, then use `execute_process` to fire up MATLAB/Simulink to generate the code.
   - If the generated code does not exist and MATLAB/Simulink was *not* found, then error out because the higher level project can't be built without the necessary generated code.

At this point if CMake hasn't errored out then the generated code should exist.

3. Note that the code generation process writes a .cmake file which does `list(APPEND SOURCES ...` and `list(APPEND HEADERS ...` to add the generated code files to the lists for the higher level project. I then use `include` in my higher level project's CMake file to update those lists before creating the CMake target.
4. If MATLAB/Simulink *was* found in step 1, then use `add_custom_command` to facilitate regeneration of the code if the Simulink model changes (if MATLAB/Simulink was not found, then this step is skipped). The code I'm using for this is:

```
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${SLX_H_FILE}
        COMMAND ${MATLABLOCATION} -sd ${SLX_DIR} -batch "commands for the ${SLX_NAME} file"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${SLX_DIR}
        DEPENDS ${SLX_NAME}
        COMMENT "Using ${MATLABLOCATION} to generate code from ${SLX_NAME}"
        VERBATIM
    )
```

where `${SLX_NAME}` is the Simulink model and I'm using `${SLX_H_FILE}` as the file it should be checking to determine whether to fire off the command or not. `${SLX_H_FILE}` is just one of the generated files, but note that it also is something added to the `HEADERS` list.

5. Create my higher level project's target using `add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})`.

### Problem

Steps 1 and 2 seem to be working fine. It correctly decides to generate the code during CMake configure if and only if it's not already there and MATLAB is found. Steps 3 and 5 are working fine in that the higher level project is correctly being made aware of the generated code files such that it compiles them along with the other files to result in the final shared library. **The issue is that the `add_custom_command` is being fired the first time I run a CMake build even though the generated code, as should be checked by the `${SLX_H_FILE}` file, *does* exist at build time so there is no reason for it to do so.** After that first build, subsequent builds only make the call to MATLAB/Simulink to regenerate the code if I change the Simulink model as intended. I suspect that there is something wrong with the way I'm setting dependencies up which is causing that undesired code regeneration, but I can't figure out what it is. The call to MATLAB can be very time consuming, so it is unacceptable to have it

### Other Notes

I have only been trying this so far running CMake from the command line and using Visual Studio 2019/MS Build Engine: `cmake -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` and then `cmake --build build --config Release`.

Comment: "`add_custom_command` is being fired the first time I run a CMake build even though the generated code, as should be checked by the ${SLX_H_FILE} file, does exist at build time" - It is possible if a build tool (msvc in your case) determine, that `${SLX_H_FILE}` is **older** than `${SLX_NAME}`. This is how most build tools determine, whether they need to regenerate an OUTPUT file because of changes in DEPENDS file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That would make sense, but I am 100% sure that ```${SLX_H_FILE}``` is **newer** than ```${SLX_NAME}``` when it happens.

Comment: "I am 100% sure that `${SLX_H_FILE}` is newer than `${SLX_NAME}` when it happens" - That is, you have checked **timestamps** of that files? Also, do you use **absolute paths** for `SLX_H_FILE` and `SLX_NAME`? Otherwise, the OUTPUT file is treated relative to the build directory, and it is unlikely that you already have that file after the first run of `cmake`.

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed with timestamps of the two files. I did have ```SLX_H_FILE``` built up to an absolute path but did not for ```SLX_NAME```. Unfortunately, making that one absolute too didn't solve the issue.

Comment: There may be other files cmake uses internally for added to the dependency list of the rule. In fact for the VS 2019 generator cmake does generate a `<maindependency>.rule` file which is the file doing the custom generate step. The whole setup here is a bit weird though: Either you generate the files or you don't; everything else would require everyone to always check in consistent versions of the files and be sure the program output is never different between all versions used. Furthermore you're probably commiting the "crime" of writing to the source dir here...

Comment: @fabian Yeah...perhaps the approach is wrong overall and I should never be trying to *pull* in generated code from the CMake and should instead always have the generated code in source control for CMake to use. And when someone needs to change a Simulink model they do so from the MATALB/Simulink side and commit both the Simulink file and the generated code. Thank you both for the thoughts!